# SearchView filter ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, searchview

I have been attempting to to filter/search the **Adapter** adapter with the **mSearch** EditText. I am looking for help with implementing **getFilter()** and so on.

This activity is currently displaying a list of content. **mSearch** is placed above the list and I would like to filter/update the list as someone types.

Let me know if you need specific pieces of code or for more information. Thank you in advance!

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

 private SearchView mSearch;
 private List<Model> mMain = new ArrayList<Model>();

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 }

 public class MainFragment extends Fragment implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {

  private ListView mListView;
  private Adapter mAdapter;

  public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
   if (mAdapter != null) {
    mAdapter.getFilter().filter(query.toString());
   }
   return false;
  }

  public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
   onQueryTextChange(query);
   return false;
  }

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_user_list_row, container, false);

    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    mAdapter = new Adapter();
    mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mListView.setAdapter.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    mSearch.setOnQueryTextListener((SearchView.OnQueryTextListener) mContext);

   return rootView;

  }

  public class Adapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

   @Override
   public int getCount() {
    return mMain.size();
   }

   @Override
   public Object getItem(int position) {
    return 1;
   }

   @Override
   public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
   }

   @Override
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = View.inflate(mContext, R.layout.main_user_list_row, null);

     if (mContext != null && mMain.get(position) != null) {
      TextView mPosition = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.position);
      mPosition.setText("...");
     }

    return view;
   }

   @Override
   public Filter getFilter() {
    return new Filter() {

     @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
     @Override
     protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
      mMain = (List<Model>) results.values;
      Adapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();
     }

     @Override
     protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
      List<Contest> filteredResults = getFilteredResults(constraint);
      FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
      results.values = filteredResults;
      return results;
     }

    };
   }

  }

}
```

I am getting this error at **getFilteredResults**

```
Cannot resolve method 'getFilteredResults(java.lang.CharSequence)'
```

I also am getting this error at **mSearch.setOnQueryTextListener((SearchView.OnQueryTextListener) mContext);**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{...MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: ...InDraftActivity cannot be cast to android.widget.SearchView$OnQueryTextListener

java.lang.ClassCastException: ...MainActivity cannot be cast to android.widget.SearchView$OnQueryTextListener
```

**SOLUTION**

I fixed the SearchView error by implementing an OnQueryTextListener in the activity, instead of the fragment.

performFiltering needed to look like

```
List<Contest> filteredResults = new ArrayList<Contest>();
FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
results.values = filteredResults;
results.count = filteredResults.size();
```

See the marked answer.

Comment: What is getFilteredResults, have you defined it? Because I have implemented this kind of code before and have never used that method before

Comment: I removed getFilteredResults and now mMain.size() is returning as null during publishResults.

Comment: well if you removed that method then what is `filteredResults` now assigned to? Isnt it null?

Comment: Does your activity implement OnQueryTextListener?

Comment: @Submersed, the activity doesn't. The MainFragment implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener

Comment: I moved the OnQueryTextListener to the activity and that fixed the problem. I didn't realize that the problem was coming from it being set in the fragment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you return your `FilterResults`, you must specify its value AND count. Currently you are just specifying the value like so...

```
results.values = filteredResults;
```

Under that line, before you return `results` in your `performFiltering(...)` method, add this line...

```
results.count = filteredResults.size();
```

EDIT: An fully working adapter with filter from a project i've done

```
class ContactsAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

    private List<Contact> mData;
    private List<Contact> database;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private Context context;
    static boolean inMarkMode = false;

    ContactsAdapter(List<Contact> mData, List<Contact> database, Context context) {
        this.mData = mData;
        this.context = context;
        this.database = database;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    /**
     * Modifies the way a contact is shown in its adapter depending on
     * displayChoice shared preference
     * 
     * @param position
     *            of the contact in its listview
     * @return <code>String</code> to display
     */
    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        switch (context.getSharedPreferences("settings",
                HomeScreenActivity.MODE_PRIVATE).getInt("displayChoice", -1)) {
        case 1:
            return mData.get(position).getLastName() + " "
                    + mData.get(position).getFirstName();
        case 2:
            return mData.get(position).getFirstName() + " "
                    + mData.get(position).getMobileNumber();
        case 3:
            return mData.get(position).getLastName() + " "
                    + mData.get(position).getMobileNumber();
        default:
            return mData.get(position).getFirstName() + " "
                    + mData.get(position).getLastName();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    /**
     * Modifies the view shown in HomeScreenActivity depending on whether the
     * user has entered mark mode or not
     * 
     * @return <code>View</code> to display
     */
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        CheckedTextView result = null;
        TextView normalResult = null;
        final String contactRow = getItem(position);

        if (inMarkMode) {// if user is in markMode, use the mark layout
            if (convertView == null) {
                result = (CheckedTextView) mInflater.inflate(
                        R.layout.home_screen_contacts_mark_view, parent, false);
            } else {
                result = (CheckedTextView) convertView;
            }
            result.setText(contactRow);
            result.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_selector);
        } else { // if user NOT in markmode, use normal contacts view layout
            if (convertView == null) {
                normalResult = (TextView) mInflater.inflate(
                        R.layout.home_screen_contacts_view, parent, false);
            } else {
                normalResult = (TextView) convertView;
            }
            normalResult.setText(contactRow);
            normalResult.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_selector);
        }

        if (inMarkMode) {
            return result;
        } else {
            return normalResult;
        }
    }

    int getItemIdAtPosition(int position) {
        return mData.get(position).getID();
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
                // If there's nothing to filter on, return the original data for
                // your list
                if (charSequence == null || charSequence.length() == 0) {
                    results.values = database;
                    results.count = database.size();
                } else {
                    List<Contact> filterResultsData = new ArrayList<Contact>();

                    // if search details is 0, search fullName, else, search
                    // all details
                    if (HomeScreenActivity.searchAllDetails == 0) {
                        for (Contact c : database) {
                            if (c.getFullName().toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH)
                                    .contains(charSequence)) {
                                filterResultsData.add(c);
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        for (Contact c : database) {
                            if (c.getAllDetailsForSearch()
                                    .toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH)
                                    .contains(charSequence)) {
                                filterResultsData.add(c);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    results.values = filterResultsData;
                    results.count = filterResultsData.size();
                }

                return results;
            }

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence,
                    FilterResults filterResults) {
                // set the data to the filter results and notifyDataSetChanged()
                mData = (List<Contact>) filterResults.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Great. Thank you. getFilteredResults is still unresolved. I thought List<Model> filteredResults = getFilteredResults(constraint); was good enough. What should I do to fix that error?

Comment: @localhost I have no idea what getFilteredResults is. You should just remove it and make `List<Contest> filteredResults` equal some arrayList, then filter the arraylist the way you want and then assign results.value and results.count then return it. I have made a contact manager app that used a filter like this, I will put it in my answer so you can look at it. Hopefully it will be of some use.